# Making the horizontal scrollbar of a scrolled panel to be permanently visible in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I am developing a GUI with wxPython v3.0 on windows 8 OS. I have a problem regarding the horizontal scroll bar on a particular scrolled panel. In my GUI there are 2 scrolled panels named as `panel1` and `panel2` added to one main scrolled panel named as `mainPanel` and this panel has a vertical scroll bar. When ever the vertical scroll bar of the `mainPanel` is moved all the panels (panel1 & panel2) move simultaneously, this is exactly what I desired. Also in `panel1` there is a horizontal scroll bar only (The vertical scroll bar is disabled on `panel1` using `SetupScrolling(scroll_y=False)`). The reason why I need a horizontal scroll bar on `panel1` is because if the text inside increases the panel expands too so I gave it a scroll bar.

**Problem:**

This horizontal bar on `panel1` is only visible when I scroll the vertical scroll bar (the scroll bar on extreme right side as shown in the image.) of the `mainPanel` to the bottom.
[image]

How can I make the horizontal scroll bar on `panel1` to be visible every time? I don't want to first scroll the vertical scroll bar of the mainPanel to the bottom in order to access the horizontal scroll bar of panel1?

**Code:** 
Here is an example code for this problem. You can also download the python file from [this link](https://db.tt/fI53tevm) if you have any problems with identations.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import wx
  import wx.lib.scrolledpanel


  class GUI(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
    screenWidth = 800
    screenHeight = 450
    screenSize = (screenWidth, screenHeight)
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=screenSize)
    locationFont = wx.Font(15, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD)
    mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    panelsSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    mainPanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1,style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
    mainPanel.SetupScrolling()
    panel1 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
    panel1.SetupScrolling(scroll_y=False)
    panel2 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
    panel1.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')
    panel2.SetBackgroundColour('#FFFFFF')
    panelsSizer.Add(panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    panelsSizer.Add(panel2, 2, wx.EXPAND)
    mainPanel.SetSizer(panelsSizer)

    k = 0
    locations = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,110,110,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    for i in range(1,20):
        locationPanels = 'locationPanel'+str(k)
        locationPanels = wx.Panel(panel1)
        label0 = str(k+1)+ '. '+'Panel-1   #############################'
        text0 = wx.StaticText(locationPanels, -1, label0)
        text0.SetFont(locationFont)
        text0.SetForegroundColour('#0101DF')
        sizer1.Add(locationPanels, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer1.Add(wx.StaticLine(panel1), 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 0)
        k += 1

    k = 0
    availability=[1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,110,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    for i in range(1,20):
        sensorPanel ='sensorPanel' +str(k)
        sensorPanel = wx.Panel(panel2)
        label = str(k)+ '. Panel-2'
        text = wx.StaticText(sensorPanel, -1, label)
        text.SetForegroundColour('#0101DF')
        text.SetFont(locationFont)
        sizer2.Add(sensorPanel, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer2.Add(wx.StaticLine(panel2), 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 0)
        k += 1

    panel1.SetSizer(sizer1)
    panel2.SetSizer(sizer2)
    mainSizer.Add(mainPanel, 15, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
    self.SetSizer(mainSizer)


if __name__=='__main__':
app = wx.App()
frame = GUI(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: looks like you are trying to implement a **Grid** ? Why not just use wx.grid.Grid ?

Comment: @Jerry_Y I am not trying to implement the Grid. This code sample is just for a minimal example of my problem. The number of values and values that will fill up the panels will be dynamically added from a server. I have a feeling that this problem will remain same even with grids. I think even the grid will expand when the text inside it expands? Any suggestions.

Comment: Your code has broken indentation. Please fix.

Comment: @Fenikso I edited my post. If still there are some issues then please download the original code files.

Comment: Weird, the second example does not give me scrollbar on the far-right.

Comment: @Fenikso, For me it is working. I tested right now. The file named code-2.py is working. I am using windows 7 OS. Could that be a case? Please try to download the original code files if possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you call method SetupScrolling with no parameters both scroll bars will be active, if you dont want the y axis scroll bar showing use scroll_y = False.

```
panel21 = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
panel21.SetupScrolling(scroll_y = False)
```

Comment: I already updated my post with the solution to my first problem You are 10 minutes late. However, I thank you. Any suggestion regarding the second problem?