# Button with an image not showing up in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I am using python v2.7 and wxPython v3.0 on Windows 7 OS. In my application I have a panel named as `myPanel`. I have a image as a background on `myPanel` the image names is `green.bmp`  The `myPanel` contains a button named as `myButton`. This `myButton` also contains an image as a background named as `blue.bmp`

**Problem**: I don't see `myButton` on `myPanel` when I execute my code. I can't figure it out why is it not working. Any help will be appreciated. *If I don't use an image as an background for `myPanel` then the `myButton` is visible!*

**Code**: The images can be downloaded from here [Green.bmp](https://db.tt/R2fhqSM3)  and [Blue.bmp](https://db.tt/TiiodAmk). The code snippet is provided below:

```
import wx

class gui(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, id, title, size=(500,400))
        myPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1, size=(300,200))
        image_file1 = 'green.bmp'
        image1 = wx.Image(image_file1, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        #---- Comment out the line below then the button is visible
        self.bitmap2 = wx.StaticBitmap(myPanel, -1, image1, (0, 0))

        myButton = wx.Button(myPanel, -1, size =(30,30), pos=(20,20))
        image_file2 = 'blue.bmp'
        image2 = wx.Image(image_file2, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.bitmap1 = wx.StaticBitmap(myButton, -1, image2, (0, 0))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gui(parent=None, id=-1, title="Test")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a parenting issue. You need to set the button's parent to be **self.bitmap2**, not **myPanel**. Otherwise, the two widgets will "stack" on top of each other.

See the following tutorial:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/

You can also diagnose this sort of thing by using the [Widget Inspection Tool](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool)

Comment: Wow, Thank you. You are a python expert! I visit your blog too, its great for beginners like me. I need to practice a lot.

Comment: Mike, if you don't mind can you please have a glance at my this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703514/making-the-horizontal-scrollbar-of-a-scrolled-panel-to-be-permanently-visible-in